# Is there a way to copy .JPG files from Android Mobile device to My Windows PC Programmatically

Tags: android

I have an Android application running on my mobile. This application needs to push some .JPG files to my Windows PC when connected through USB.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality programmatically (thru Android Code).

Comment: Why do you need Java code? `adb pull` works fine

Comment: I want the Andriod App to push the files from Mobile to PC.